# Spring boot Oauth2 + Angular CORS problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I am new in making auth services. When i try get acces token form Postman everything working fine. But when i use Angular i got this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8082/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

My config is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthMsApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthMsApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

---

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@WebFilter("/*")
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, x-requested-with, authorization");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    @Configuration
    public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String READ = "read";
        private static final String WRITE = "write";
        private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
        private static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";

        @Value("${client.id}")
        private String clientId;
        @Value("${client.secret}")
        private String clientSecret;
        @Value("${tokenSignature}")
        private String tokenSignature;
        @Value("${accessTokenValiditySeconds}")
        private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;
        @Value("${refreshTokenValiditySeconds}")
        private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

        private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        private final UserDetailsService customDetailsService;

        public OAuth2Config(@Qualifier("authenticationProviderImpl") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                            UserDetailsService customDetailsService) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
            this.customDetailsService = customDetailsService;
        }

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
            JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            converter.setSigningKey(tokenSignature);
            return converter;
        }

        @Bean
        public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwtTokenStore(tokenEnhancer());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .accessTokenConverter(tokenEnhancer())
                    .userDetailsService(customDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
            security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            String encodedClientSecret = encoder().encode(clientSecret);
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient(clientId)
                    .secret(encodedClientSecret)
                    .scopes(READ, WRITE)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes(PASSWORD, REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds);
        }
    }
```

Any searching info not working as global CORS. One thing is working it's

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

But i can put this on my own controllers, and i dont know how set it for oauth/token endpoint.

this official doc solution doesnt work.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html

filter doesnt work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days i found solution. At firs i remove all filters in my auth service. Second i add this props in my gateway service:

```
cloud:
gateway:
  globalcors:
    corsConfigurations:
      '[/**]':
        allowedOrigins: "*"
        allowedHeaders:
          - content-type
          - x-requested-with
          - Authorization
        allowedMethods:
          - GET
          - POST
          - OPTIONS
          - DELETE
          - PUT
```

You just need add global headers for all your services in gateway props, also this can combine with filters in services for more flexible settings.
I hope this can help for some one to save 3 days)

Comment: How is this different than what's done in `doFilter()`? I have the same issue as you, but I don't have any gateway config in my Java app.

Comment: This is not working for me. Any other advise?

Answer (score -1):

This is a common issue everywhere,
since the origins are different it protects the injection of different origins.

Solution :

1) if you are using for dev then enable CORS on chrome (Extension) (POSTMAN do it by default)

2) In production, the angular application where it is hosted should white list you API URL,

3) third set cors allow origin headers